# Need to populate textbox via value of selectbox, multiple textboxes and selectlists

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, double-click, selectlist

Hey guys I have a table that has a main row, a row with a textbox and row with a selectlist that has values of premade comments that when double clicked on need to be populated into the textbox just above it. I am able to get the value of the selected list item into a variable but I can't seem to find the textbox I am looking for. This is all ran by our DB so I am using classes instead of ids and need to find the previous item with the class name. Heres my code, any help would be great.

NOTE: I am not including the document.ready wrapper but it is in my code.

```
   $(".mfValues").dblclick(function () {
            var val = $(this).attr("value")
           // alert(val);
            $(this).prev(".mfTextComments").val(val);
        });

   <tr><td><textarea class="mfTextComments" runat="server" cols="20" rows="2" ></textarea></td></tr>";
   <tr><td><select runat=\"server\" style=\"height:20px;\" title=\"Please select a comment from this list by double clicking the comment or create your own in the text area above.\" size=\"4\">
    <option class="mfValues" value="Value1"\">Value1</option>
    <option class="mfValues" value="Value2"\">Value1</option>
    <option class="mfValues" value="Value3"\">Value1</option>
    </select></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, just need to get out of the < tr > :

```
$(".mfValues").dblclick(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val();
    $this.closest('tr').prev().find(".mfTextComments").val(val);
});​
```

Comment: Thanks that did teh trick! I'm still learning how to group functions together, and this helped a lot.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the multiple edits - I kept typo'ing :)

Comment: NP. One thing tho you have an extra unneeded line for the variable the way I have it set to one line works perfectly.

Comment: Yea but it's always good to cache your selectors if you plan to use it more than once. By caching $(this) it's saved in memory vs having to go out and select it again. Just a performance enhancement.

Comment: ahh I see, I don't need it held in memory, once it is in the textarea the user can add to the comment line or just hit submit then it is sent to the server and everything is handled there. Its just a way of giving our employees a faster way of commenting what they are working on.